# Math.pow and Math.sqrt formula returning value of 0

Tags: java, math

So I don't think I'm bad at math, and I don't think translating simple math distance formulas into code is that difficult if I knew what I was doing. Which apparently I don't. Long story short, I'm supposed to calculate the distance between two 3D points and for some reason, my formula isn't working correctly. I don't know if I just wrote it wrong or if something is off, because I've written it multiple times and it still doesn't work right.

This is my `public class Distance`, which has my distance formula

```
public class Distance
{
    Distance () {}

    double d;
    double x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2;

    public void setD (double d) 
    {
        this.d = d;
    }

    double distance ()
    {
/*      return Math.sqrt ( Math.pow (( x2 - x1 ), 2 ) 
                                + Math.pow (( y2 - y1 ), 2 )
                                + Math.pow (( z2 - z1 ), 2 ));

*/
        return Math.sqrt ( ( x2 - x1 ) * ( x2 - x1 ) 
                                + ( y2 - y1 ) * ( y2 - y1 ) 
                                + ( z2 - z1 ) * ( z2 - z1 ) );
    }

}
```

I've tried writing it two ways, both of which test to 0 (I'm using a nested `for` loop, with all variables looping up to 3, to test before I write for user input).

If anyone could explain why I'm getting this problem, it would be much appreciated.

Edit: I know people are telling me to initialize to a certain value. I'm pretty sure I initialized it in my test loop, which I realize I should have posted for clarity.

```
class Distance_test
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        Distance line = new Distance ();

        double d;

        for ( double x1 = 0; x1 <= 2; x1++ )
        {
            line.setD ( x1 );
            d = line.distance();

            for ( double x2 = 0; x2 <= 2; x2++ )
            { 
                line.setD ( x2 );

                for ( double y1 = 0; y1 <= 2; y1++ )
                {
                    line.setD ( y1 );

                    for ( double y2 = 0; y2 <= 2; y2++ )
                    {
                        line.setD ( y2 );

                        for ( double z1 = 0; z1 <= 2; z1++ )
                        {
                            line.setD ( z1 );

                            for ( double z2 = 0; z2 <= 2; z2++ )
                            {
                                line.setD ( z2 );

                            System.out.printf ( "\n Distance of 3D line with points %.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f is %.2f\n", x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2, line.distance() );   

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, I do think it's a bit messy but I'm just trying to get it to work first before I get it to look nicer.

Comment: Looks like C#, not c++. Also, where are you assigning `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`, `z1`, `z2`? If these variables aren't initialized they will all default to 0.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was doing another C++ assignment and I got my tags mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2` are not initialized. You should be initializing them, not d, which is the result of your computation.

If memory serves me right, Java is initializing doubles to zero, if this was C++, your variable would contain random data and your result would be random as well.

Other than that your code is fine.

Also, you should be implementing this as a function, not a class. You get some input, you produce a result - that's a function.

```
double calculateDistance(double[] point1, double[] point2)
{
x1 = point1[0]; // Or you can use enum or something for the index
y1 = point1[1];
z1 = point1[2];

x2 = point2[0];
y2 = point2[1];
z2 = point2[2];

return Math.sqrt ( Math.pow (( x2 - x1 ), 2 ) 
                                + Math.pow (( y2 - y1 ), 2 )
                                + Math.pow (( z2 - z1 ), 2 ));
}
```

Since this is Java you can wrap this in static class called "MathFunctions" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely is C# or Java, not C++.

The biggest thing I'm not seeing is an assignment to the x, y, and z variables.  If those aren't set, then I would expect them to be undefined or zero, which would then mean the result would be 0.

You need to set those those values that go into Pow and Sqrt to get a valid result.